Ubuntu Server が Desktop よりアイドル時の電力消費が大きいのはなぜですか？
環境:
AMD Ryzen CPU / Nvidia RTS GPU 他

Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 アイドル時 43W
Ubuntu Server 24.04 アイドル時 62W
(※スマートコンセントにて測定　両方ともクリーンインストール直後。拡張的なサービスはSSHぐらいしかいれてないです。）

上記の通り、明らかにServerのほうがアイドル時の電力消費が大きいですが、DesktopのGUIのシステム設定にあるような省電力設定がされていないからですか？
だとしたらServerでも同じ設定をする方法はありますか？

PowerTOP 辺りを使ってまずは原因を探るところから始めてみてください。 参考: Ubuntuマシンを省電力化する方法

もしも問題が解決したのなら回答を承認するなど行ってみてください。
参考: 自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？
/ まだ解決していないのなら, 質問点を絞り込むなど行うとよいかも
参考: 良い質問をするには？


DesktopのGUIのシステム設定にあるような省電力設定がされていないからですか？
だとしたらServerでも同じ設定をする方法はありますか？

原因が, 省電力設定だと仮定 するなら
以下のように設定することができます
以下, ラズパイ 4 にて cpufrequtils を利用する方法
$ sudo apt install cpufrequtils

使用例
$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: cpufreq-dt
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 600 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 600 MHz, 700 MHz, 800 MHz, 900 MHz, 1000 MHz, 1.10 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 600 MHz and 1.80 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.70 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 600 MHz:36.40%, 700 MHz:9.67%, 800 MHz:4.73%, 900 MHz:2.36%, 1000 MHz:1.92%, 1.10 GHz:2.14%, 1.20 GHz:1.59%, 1.30 GHz:1.97%, 1.40 GHz:2.24%, 1.50 GHz:2.20%, 1.60 GHz:1.71%, 1.70 GHz:1.71%, 1.80 GHz:31.37%  (3024)


4つの CPU 0 から CPU 3 まで表示される
hardware limits: 600 MHz - 1.80 GHz ... この範囲で周波数を設定できる
current CPU frequency is 1.70 GHz. ... カレント周波数は 1.70 GHz になっている
powersave, performance など指定できる
現在は "ondemand" と思われ, 負荷に応じて周波数が切り替わる, はず

設定例
sudo cpufreq-set -g powersave

内容確認
  current policy: frequency should be within 600 MHz and 1.80 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 600 MHz.


他に cpupower なども存在します
参考: (docs.redhat.com) 3.2.3. CPUfreq ポリシーおよび速度のチューニング

cpupower frequency-info
cpupower frequency-set

これらのツールのまとめは archlinux が一番詳しいようです
参考: (wiki.archlinux.jp) CPU 周波数スケーリング

cpufreq, cpupower 以外にも GUIと思しきものも紹介されています


上記のツールで全く有効化できない場合
カーネル構成で無効化されている可能性があるかもしれません
その場合, kernel configurationやり直しを検討してみてください
